# Is it possible to dynamically show/hide frequently used buttons with full CKEditor.inline toolbar using maybe a "More” button?

Tags: javascript, web, ckeditor, toolbar, rich-text-editor

CKEditor provides ability to display inline editor dynamically on click of textarea and set of toolbar buttons can be configured to show/hide but is it possible to show only frequently used buttons and hide rest of the buttons with "More” button/option because i want to provide full CKEditor toolbar but some of the toolbar buttons are rarely used and would like to hide to simplify user interface it if possible

In other words, i want to keep all buttons which are available in full CKEditor but would like to hide it under may be an option called “More”

```
config.toolbar = [
    { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ], items: [ 'Source', '-', 'Save', 'NewPage', 'Preview', 'Print', '-', 'Templates' ] },
    { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ], items: [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo', 'pbckcode' ] },
    { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ], items: [ 'Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', '-', 'Scayt' ] },
    { name: 'forms', items: [ 'Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton', 'HiddenField' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ], items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ], items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl', 'Language' ] },
    { name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor' ] },
    { name: 'insert', items: [ 'Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak', 'Iframe' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'styles', items: [ 'Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize' ] },
    { name: 'colors', items: [ 'TextColor', 'BGColor' ] },
    { name: 'tools', items: [ 'Maximize', 'ShowBlocks' ] },
    { name: 'others', items: [ 'YouTube', '-' ] },
    //{ name: 'about', items: [ 'About' ] }
    { name: 'misc', items: [ 'Mathjax', 'mathedit', 'EqnEditor', 'Equation', 'Youtube', 'lineutils', 'widget' ] }
];
```

thanks